# flutter displaying picture at the bottom of a scrollable screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter app, and I have a Listview widget I made as follows:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  List<int> list2 = [];
  list2 = [1];

  return new Scaffold(
  body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                print("i: ${i}");
                return listRow(valuepassed: i);
              },
            ),
          );
```

The widget adds rows to the screen based on a floatingactionbutton to either add a row or delete a row and it is scrollable.  What I would like to do is add a picture to the bottom of the screen that is either covered up by the listview when enough elements are added, or is moved lower on the scrollable screen when more elements are added.  If you need more information to solve this problem please let me know but I think this should do it and your help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list

Comment: Thanks @gugga!  I will look into it after dinner.  In the meantime I'm going to leave the question open but if I can figure it out I will for sure give you credit for the answer.  Thanks again!